# Naming inserted worksheet like another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to add a new sheet in a workbook and name it exactly like the active worksheet but with a `'` after it. 
So if the name of the active sheet is `0908` then I want the name of the newly inserted worksheet to be `0908'`.

I searched a bit and I saw how to name a sheet with a reference to somewhere else, but only for values inside other worksheets.

That's the code for referencing inside other worksheets.

```
Worksheets.add.Name = Worksheets("MENU").Range("B2").value
```

Comment: You can't use the apostrophe in a worksheet's name.

Comment: @Variatus you can, but not as last character.

Comment: @Peh Interesting. Thank you. I also learned that you can't use it at the beginning, either :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that should work.

```
Worksheets.add.Name = ActiveSheet.Name & "xxx"
```

You just need to read the name of the active sheet and append a string to it.

But an apostrophe at the end of a sheet doesn't work!
This is only allowed if it is followed by another character like:

```
Worksheets.add.Name = ActiveSheet.Name & "'s"
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for code like this.

```
Dim WsName As String
Dim Ws As Worksheet

WsName = ActiveSheet.Name
Set Ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheet(Worksheets.Count))
Ws.Name = WsName & "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have to have a character after the " ' ", you could use

```
Worksheets.Add.Name = ActiveSheet.Name & "' "
```

Adding the space after the ' would give the effect that you were looking for.